# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 0 input samples and 121 target samples

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do a 6-class classification. Here is the code:

```
############### CONFIG_CNN3D ##############
RESULT_PATH = 'results3d'
MODEL_NAME = 'saved3d'
MODEL = 'cnn3d'
CHANCE = .01
TEST_TRAIN_SPLIT = .2
SIZE3D = (64, 64)
DEPTH = 3
CHANNELS = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 128
EPOCHS = 30
EXTRACT = False
############### CONFIG ##############

categories = ['Basketball', 'Biking', 'Bowling', 'Diving', 'Haircut', 'PlayingGuitar']

def load_data3d():
    ret_X = []
    ret_y = []
    for train_or_test in 'train', 'test':
        data = []
        labels = []
        for label, category in enumerate(categories):
            files = glob.glob(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, CLIP_PATH, train_or_test, category, '*.avi'))
            print("%3d. Category %-50s  %-7d files" % (label, category, len(files)))
            for file in files:
                print('Loaded',file)
                video = Video(file)
                frame_array = []
                for index in range(len(video)-5):
                    frame=video.read()
                    if config3d.CHANNELS == 1:
                        frame = im2gray(frame).reshape(*frame.shape[:-1], 1)
                    frame_array.append(frame)
                frame_array = np.array(frame_array)
                data.append(frame_array)
                labels.append(label)
        print("Shape of data:",np.array(data).shape)
        if not config3d.EXTRACT:
            X = np.array(data).transpose((1, 0))
            X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], *config3d.SIZE3D, config3d.DEPTH, config3d.CHANNELS))
            X = X / 255
        else:
            from .extractor import Extractor
            extractor = Extractor()
            X = []
            for frame_array in data:
                frame_array = extractor.extract(frame_array)
                X.append(frame_array)
            X = np.array(X)
        y = np.array(labels)
        y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, len(categories))

        print('X_%s.shape:' % train_or_test, X.shape)
        print('y_%s.shape:' % train_or_test, y.shape)

        ret_X.append(X)
        ret_y.append(y)
    return ret_X + ret_y
```

when i run it i get the result

```
Shape of data: (121, 0)
X_train.shape: (0, 64, 64, 3, 1)
y_train.shape: (121, 6)
```

and error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fit3d.py", line 16, in <module>
    verbose=True)
  File "C:\Users\VCTrung\anaconda3\envs\mypython3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1002, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\VCTrung\anaconda3\envs\mypython3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\VCTrung\anaconda3\envs\mypython3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1490, in _standardize_user_data
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "C:\Users\VCTrung\anaconda3\envs\mypython3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 220, in _check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 0 input samples and 121 target samples.
```

The "ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 0 input samples and 121 target samples".
I don't understand why the input is 0. Please help me with the solution and the necessary modifications to the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your X_train shape is absurd. According to your 121 target samples, your X_train should be (121, H, W, C). (H, W, and C are the Height, width and channels of the input image).

Answer (score 0):

> Considering the channels and depth you are mentioning is same. You can replace your code using this snippet. The output shape of the X_train should be (121, 64, 64, 1).

```
        X = np.array(data)
        X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], *config3d.SIZE3D, config3d.CHANNELS))
        X = X / 255
```

Comment: I got a error message : 
`X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], *config3d.SIZE3D, config3d.CHANNELS))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (110,64,64,1)`